# Show that the trajectory is a straight line.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I'm having difficulty answering an exercise for a course in Vector Calculus.

> Consider the following trajectory
>
> $$\mathbf{r}(t) = \frac{A}{\cos(\theta(t)) -
> B\sin(\theta(t))}\hat{\rho}(\theta(t))$$
>
> where $A$ and $B$ are constants and $\hat{\rho}(\theta(t)) =
>  \cos(\theta(t))\hat{\mathbf{i}} +\sin(\theta(t))\hat{\mathbf{j}}$, and $\theta(t)$ is a general function dependent on time.
>   Show that $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is a straight line.

I've attempted to show it by letting $\cos(\theta(t)) = \frac{x}{r}$ and $\sin(\theta(t)) = \frac{y}{r}$ and some cancellation occurs but I end up with $x - By$ in the denominator, which isn't good.

Comment: What is $\theta(t)$?

Comment: @Hetebrij Woops! Meant to include that.

Comment: This is not true...for straight lines, the ratio of the scalar functions of $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ is constant. $\tan(\theta(t))$ certainly is not a constant function in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbf{r} = \frac{A\cos \theta}{\cos \theta - B\sin \theta}\hat{\mathbf i} + \frac{A\sin \theta}{\cos \theta - B\sin \theta}\hat{\mathbf j} = (x,y)$$

$$\frac1A x - \frac{B}{A} y = 1 \implies y = \frac1B x - \frac{A}{B}$$

Which shows that $\mathbf{r}$ is a straight line.

Comment: Why the downvote? What's wrong with my approach? Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: This is the answer that's given so... :s

Comment: Your answer is fine.  +1

Answer (score 1):

If $\vec r=\hat \rho\,\frac{A}{\cos(\theta)-B\sin(\theta)}$, then we have

$$x=\frac{A\cos(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)-B\sin(\theta)}=\frac{Ax}{x-By}\\\\
y=\frac{A\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)-B\sin(\theta)}=\frac{Ay}{x-By}$$

from which we see that

$$x=By+A$$

And we are done!

Comment: Thanks, I was writing down several properties of straight lines and just trying to force one of the conditions onto this trajectory and just hoping something would drop out!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark